# Why unix_timestamp('1970-01-02'); returns 66600 instead of 86400 ( 60 x 60 x 24 ) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Why does `unix_timestamp('1970-01-02')` return 66600 instead of 86400 ( 60 x 60 x 24 ) in mysql?

How to get the correct value from mysql?

Comment: I can hardly see how that relates to the Java Programming Language itself; maybe you should add some details and code ((the difference of 5:30 hours strongly suggest that this is timezone related - I believe India has *for example* that offset to UTC))

Comment: Your timezone +05:30, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document says;

> If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. The server interprets date as a value in the session time zone and converts it to an internal Unix timestamp value in UTC.

I assume your timezone is +05:30. This might be the reason why.